# How to Implement a Callback in Methods that uses @Async (Springboot App)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, callback

I have a need to implement a callback-like solution to be notified of the success/failure of method calls. These methods I am calling are in a Springboot app and they are all asynchronous. More specifically, they all use the `@Async` annotation.

I have not been successful in finding a solution to this and was wondering whether others may have some ideas. I cannot use another async method (that is, I cannot change the existing code to remove the `@Async` and use something in its place). However, I can modify the method bodies themselves to add any callback capability.

Thank you.

Comment: That is what a `Future` is for. Return a `Future` from the `@Async` method and check the result. However, be careful as this might suddenly make things blocking instead of async when done wrong!

Comment: You could also try Spring events. They use a a publisher/listener model, can be transactionally configured, and the listeners can be asynchronous themselves. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events for more information.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using CompletableFuture based on your bringing it to my attention. I have not finished implemetation, but may update this ticket with that as a result. Thanks!

Comment: @LeeGreiner thanks for your input. I am implementing with CompletableFuture. thanks for your input nevertheless.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am in the middle of implementing a solution based on your suggestions. I wasn't sure how to give you credit. I answered my post myself giving you the nod for the help. Not sure whether that was the correct way to give you credit or not. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of M. Derium (above) I am using CompletableFuture for my solution. I am still in the process of implementing and testing, but it seems to be a good solutions. Here is a good reference: [Guide to CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just create a new Interface with two methods, and then pass a implementation parameter to the async method.

```
public interface TaskCallBack {
    
    void success(int code);
    void fail(int code);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I am implementing with CompletableFuture. thanks for your input nevertheless.

Comment: is it based on pooling approach ? or any success or fail it'll send notif to consumer?